# Error al intentar conectar Android Studio con MySQL a través de JDBC

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, jdbc

Soy nuevo en Android Studio (aunque llevo 35 años programando en otros entornos) y llevo días intentando conectar mi primera app con una bbdd MySQL preexistente en un servidor sin conseguirlo, así que seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal.

He descargado el driver mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar y lo he añadido a la carpeta libs como libreria, cosa que me ha generado automáticamente la dependencia:

```
implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar'
```

En el *build.gradle*.

Por lo que he podido aprender de mis consultas a este foro, he realizado este código en un metodo de mi *MainActivity.java*:

```
   final String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostingmysql292.nominalia.com/bbdd";
   final String user = "Usuario_2";
   final String password = "Password";

   try {

       Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Id=1;");

       String Email,Contrasena;
       Email = rs.getString("Email");
       Contrasena = rs.getString("Contrasena");
   }
   catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (InstantiationException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Pero lo único que obtengo es este error en la linea:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.primeraapp, PID: 3512
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Could not execute method** for android:onClick
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> ***at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)***
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:317)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:186)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
> at com.example.primeraapp.MainActivity.Busca_A_LA_BBDD(MainActivity.java:104)
> at com.example.primeraapp.MainActivity.ComprovaLogin(MainActivity.java:60)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
> Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
> (?[\w+:%]+)\s*(?://(?[^/?#]*))?\s*(?:/(?!\s*/)(?[^?#]*))?(?:?(?!\s*?)(?[^#]*))?(?:\s*#(?.*))?
> ^
> at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
> at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
> at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:394)
> at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
> at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.(ConnectionUrlParser.java:89)
> ... 20 more

Al principio lo intenté con:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Pero he visto que alguien en el foro dice que hay que añadir el cj. y usarlo así:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

**(De hecho me daba el mismo error)**

Veo que en el error que me da hay una línea que dice:

> Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
> (?[\w+:%]+)\s*(?://(?[^/?#]*))?\s*(?:/(?!\s*/)(?[^?#]*))?(?:?(?!\s*?)(?[^#]*))?(?:\s*#(?.*))?

Y creo que el error viene por aquí, pero no sé como resolverlo.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error te da porque la expresión regular no es válida. Estoy viendo que esta construcción `(?` tal y como la tienes aquí `(?[\w+:%]+)` y en más sitios no es una expresión válida. ¿Qué se supone que debe reconocer esta expresión?

Comment: Hola sergiomse, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ese es mi problema, no soy consciente de haber puesto ninguna expresión regular en mi código (además de que no sé como usarlas)

Comment: Cierto, en realidad el problema está en el código de alguna librería que estás usando, en esta clase `com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser`. No sé muy bien que librería estás usando pero a mí las expresiones regulares que usa no me compilan.

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas añadiendo el port ? `final String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostingmysql292.nominalia.com:3306/bbdd";`

Comment: sergiomse, Ya he localizado la linea, y asigna este pattern a una variable que nunca usa, asi que iba a borrar la linea y quedarme tan ancho, pero el archivo es de solo lectura porque está decompilado del bytecode..... asi que lo único que se me ocurre es probar con otra versión de la libreria. ¿Crees que puede ayudar?

Comment: Hola Frango Balsamo, muchas gracias. Lo acaba de pobar, y me da el mismo error. ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: ¿Puedes probar a importarlo en gradle así: `implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22'`?

Comment: Ok. Probado. Gracias!, pero me da un error al sicncronizar el gradle, tanto si lo pongo tal cual como si le sustituyo los dos puntos por un guión.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido querer conectar a una base de datos remota desde el cliente de Android usando JDBC, la forma habitual de interactuar con contenido remoto es mediante una API, usando Retrofit u otra herramienta, incluso si quieres pasar parte de esos datos en local, en cuyo caso lo más recomendable es usar Room. El enfoque que intentas aquí tiene muchos escollos: desde el costo de conectar los varios miles o millones de usuarios de la App de este modo, hasta el tema de autorizar conexiones remotas indiscriminadamente, etc. No es viable por donde quiera que lo mires.

Answer (score 1):

[08/06/2021]

Debido a que esta pregunta es recurrente y las respuestas se encuentran repartidas en varios lugares aqui va un resumen.

1.- Descarga el JDBC de la pagina de mysql, estoy usando el release 6.0.6 m5, descomprime el zip.

[image: Java Db connector 5.1.49 compatible con Android.]

2. Copia y pega el archivo: mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar en el folder "libs" de  tu proyecto en Android Studio.

3.- Da click derecho sobre al archivo copiado para que aparezca el menu contexual, da click en "Add As Library...".
En este punto agregara una referencia en build.gradle(app):

```
implementation files('libs\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar')
```

4A.- Agrega estas librerias a tu activity o servicio:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

4B.- Agrega el permiso de internet al manifest de tu project.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

5.- Pega este codigo en tu aplicacion:

```
String gURL = "jdbc:mysql://";
String gIP = "192.168.0.91";
String gPORT = "3306";
String gDATABASE = "pepe_db";
String gUSR = "root";
String gPSW = "";

public Connection CONN()
{
    final String class_jdbc = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(class_jdbc);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(gURL + gIP + ":" + gPORT + "/" + gDATABASE, gUSR, gPSW);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERROR1", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR2", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR3", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

private String Query_Version()
{
    String response = "";

    try {
        Connection ConnexionMySQL = CONN();
        Statement st = ConnexionMySQL.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
        //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \"%version%\"");

        while (rs.next()) {
            response += rs.getString(1) + "\r\n";
        }
        rs.close();
        ConnexionMySQL.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return response;
}

public void DoOnThread()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            String mResult = Query_Version();
            Log.e("MYSQL Version", mResult);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

6.- Instala un Servidor MYSQL en tu PC o Telefono y crea  una nueva **database**, configura las variables globales de acuerdo a tu caso, IP, PORT, DataBase name, User y Password.

7.- En mi caso estoy ejecutando la query para saber la version de la Base de Datos, MariaDB. El resultado:

[image: Log de la app al correr una Query de MYSQL.]

Estoy usando Android Studio 4.2.2

En un telefono Moto G8 con Android 11.

Saludos, espero les sirva.

Nota1: A la fecha de publicacion de esta respuesta el ultino conector es el: **Connector/J 8.0.26**, pero el **5.1.49-bin.jar** fue el mas reciente que funciono.
Nota2: Ejecutar siempre en un Thread separado del principal.

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), recuerda ser conciso en tu respuesta y limitarte a contestar por lo que preguntan. Si quieres hacer aportes a la comunidad puedes elaborar preguntas auto respondidas; te sugiero revisar la otra respuesta para ver un ejemplo de una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas llamando la conexión desde una clase main, debes aprender y tomar en cuenta que Android esta ejecutando las vistas con código JAVA en primer plano
las conexiones van a generar un Delay (*retraso mientras carga la conexión*), por lo que al hacer esas conexiones, necesitas ejecutarlas en segundo plano, con esto me refiero a que los teléfonos actualmente tienen por lo menos 2 procesadores (*2 hilos*).

El hilo 1 es para el primer plano, donde se están cargando las vistas, las animaciones y los eventos como el onClick, el hilo 2 será el encargado de ejecutar en segundo plano, cargando datos desde bases de datos o desde Apis rest.

Para ejecutar tareas en segundo plano puedes usar librerías de Android.

*En mi caso aprendí y recomiendo aprender utilizando "AsyncTask".*

**AsynckTask** se encarga de ejecutar tareas en segunda plano, para ello necesitas crear una subClase dentro de la clase donde vas a instanciar la conexión, ejemplo:

```
#   public class categoriasFragment extends Fragment {
#    ...
#    // metodo para ejecutar async
#    public void cargarConexion() {
#      //  instancia de la subclase
#      CategoriasAsync async = new CategoriasAsync ();
#      // ejecucion de la subclase
#        async.execute();
#    }
#
#    public class CategoriasAsync 
#                      extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Categoria>>{
#
#        @Override
#        protected List<Menu> doInBackground(String... strings) {
#              // el metodo do in background, como lo dice en español 
#              // "hacer en segundo plano"
#              // se encarga de realizar la conexion y
#              // la recolexion de datos que son fuera de la app
#            List<Categoria> lista = new ArrayList<>();
#            try {
#              Conexion con = new Conexion();
#              lista = con.obtenerCategorias();
#               // estos 2 codigos de conexion y recolección de datos,
#               // generaran un delay en el Thread
#               // si esto fuera en primer plano,
#               // las animaciones no podrian cargar
#               // hasta que la conexion se realize por completo
#            } catch (Exception e) {
#               // error en la conexion
#            }
#           return lista;
#        }
#
#        @Override
#        protected void onPostExecute(List<Categoria> categorias) {
#            super.onPostExecute(categorias);
#              // aqui se ejecuta la transicion de datos
#              // despues de haber descargado los datos,
#              // puedes asignarlos a una ListView desde este metodo
#              // este metodo hace conexion a primer plano
#             Adaptador adapter = new Adaptador(categorias,context,R.layout.item);
#             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
#              // asi ya estaras mostrando los datos en la vista
#              // cuando estos terminen de ser descargados
#            }
#        }
#    }
#
#}
```

**AsynckTask** es una librería efectiva para aprender, *pero es una librería en estado "deprecated", a partir de Android 11*, es mejor utilizar otras librerías que no dejan de ser el mismo procedimiento de los *AsyncTask*, pero ahora hay que tomar en cuenta que los nuevos teléfonos traen mejores procesadores y necesitamos expandir las cargas de datos a otros hilos. Actualmente los teléfonos tienen un promedio de 4 hilos, por lo que se necesita desarrollar apps que aprovechen esa capacidad y no solo 2 hilos como lo hacia el *AsyncTask*.

**Tu dirías:** ah pero con el *AsyncTask* es suficiente..

No actualmente las apps no solo están cargando una lista o una conexión, la tendencia es que todos los datos están en la nube, y cuando cargas una lista, puede que estés cargando imágenes en la lista, por lo que estas ejecutando varias conexiones al mismo tiempo.

- Una para la lista
- Otras para descargar la imagen y colocarla en cada ítem de la lista

Por eso se necesita aprovechar la potencia de 4 hilos, para ejecutar estas tareas de forma rápida y ordenada.

Espero haberte ayudado ;)

Comment: Genial!, Muchas gracias. Ya me funciona.
Solo habia que poner el mismo código pero en otro hilo.
Ahora, "solo" me queda aprender a manejar threads con metodos actuales.
Repito, Muchas gracias!